# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$last3daysMean$1: (string) => double)

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

```
val columns = 
  Seq("userid","event_first_login_time","event_last_login_time","event_retention_str")
  
val data = Seq(
("780224", "2020-12-16","2021-08-05","1,5,1,180,1,44"),
   
("780225", "2020-12-16","2021-05-06",",1,2,1,3,14,1,13,2,5,1,28,1,29,4,1,8,1,18,2,1"))
  val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)
  df.show(false)
  
def last3daysMean: (String) => (Double) = (str: String) => {

    val list = str.split(",")
    var total = 0.0
     for (i <- str.length-3 to  str.length-1) {
         total += list(i).toInt;
      }
      var avg= total/3
      avg  }

val convertUDF = udf(last3daysMean)

var df4 = df.withColumn("last3days_mean", convertUDF(col("event_retention_str")))

df4.show(10,false)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is because of an indexing error. In your `for` loop you are indexing against the input string, not against the array split against the ','. If you read through the stack trace there will be an index out of bounds exception in their somewhere. A more idiomatic version of your function would look like:

```
def last3daysMean: (String) => (Double) = (str: String) => {
  str.split(",")
    .takeRight(3)
    .map(_.toInt)
    .sum / 3.0
 }
```

When using UDFs be care of `null` values. Your `df4` expression should include a `when...otherwise` check to make sure that you don't pass any nulls into the UDF.